# Is it possible to infer string to number in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have next type:

```js
type NumberToString<T extends number> = `${T}`;
```

Is it possible to infer `NumberToString` in other direction ?

```js
    type NumberToString<T extends number> = `${T}`;
    type StringToNumber<T extends NumberToString<number>> = T extends `${infer R}` ? R extends number ? R : never : never;
    type Result = StringToNumber<'5'>

type Result = StringToNumber<'5'> // never, but I'd like to be 5
```

I'm interested in solution without any mapping. It should be completely generic and it should be literal typescript type, not value

I mean, next code should work

```js
type Result = StringToNumber<'9525'> // 9525 as number
```

I'd willing to bet that it is impossible

Comment: What's wrong with `parseInt`? Trying to do this at compile-time seems... error prone.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm interested only in literal types. Sorry, I was not clear enough

Comment: Ah ok, you don't want type number, you want *type 5*. Got it.

Comment: @JaredSmith exactly, I want 5 as a literal type

Comment: Workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type/69090186#69090186

Comment: Marking this question as a duplicate of [TypeScript Template Literal Type - how to infer numeric type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type), which you'd linked @captain-yossarian: That question is newer, but it has your accepted answer, so it seems pretty reasonable to direct readers there even if this one is cleaner or more general.

Comment: @Jeff Bowman. Thanks a lot, you are right.

Comment: It is doable since TS 4.8 . See [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094)