# TypeScript Convert string union type to number union type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to convert string union type to number union type in TypeScript?

e.g. Given a union type A:

```typescript
type A = '7' | '8' | '9'
```

Convert to:

```typescript
type B = 7 | 8 | 9
```

The numbers in `A` can be *any* number, not just digits or integers.

Comment: Same question but without answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410801/is-it-possible-to-infer-string-to-number-in-typescript

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible (as of typescript 4.8.4), using type inference:

```
type ToNumber<S> = S extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never

type A = "7" | "8" | "9" | "0.11" | "1.52"

type B = ToNumber<A>
```

This unfortunately cannot handle any other number formats, even in 5.2.0-beta (so `1.2e3`, `0xff4`, `0b1110` are off the table).

[Playground Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gOQK4FsBGEBOAeAygPigF4pcoIAPYCAOwBMBnKAAwBIBvASxoDMsoE5KrUZQaqDJgC+zKAH4BUAFxiIANywBYAFA7QkKAEFiUAEQB2U1AA+ZgBxXbpgJyOzABgB0ARm9vT3p4ArABMpjp64NAAQibwyOhY2Ib4QA)

Comment: Can we summarize what is happening like so?

1. Create a new type `N` using `infer`. `N` is a number.
2. Wrap that up as a string and see if `S` is compatible (`extends`) with this. In other words, is `S` a 'number-like string?'
3. If it is, return this number, therein converting `S` to a number.

Probably 1) and 2) are somewhat interchangeable in terms of the order that this is read in.

Comment: That seems roughly right, but the conditional `S extends ...` limits the types returned for `N` to only those that can be 'stringified' to `S`

Answer (score 1):

Going from `string` to number is not possible, as far as I know. However, how about the other way around, would that work for you? You can do this by using template literals:

```
type B = 7 | 8 | 9;

type A = `${B}`;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDsUA+UAcaoE4DcAUAaJFAIIJQAGAJAN4wC+VhBAxgPYB2AzsFAEMAXLEoBGQp178ARiLiIkk7nyhsRFRAHIAbFuXSoAEw2UtSfUA)