# TypeScript Template Literal Type - how to infer numeric type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

```
// from a library
type T = null | "auto" | "text0" | "text1" | "text2" | "text3" | "text4";

//in my code
type N = Extract<T, `text${number}`> extends `text${infer R}` ? R : never
```

([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDMCcHsFtQIagDYEsBGkGQJ4FgAoAFxwAcBTUAFVAF5QA7AV2WVAB9QAiBJo6Lh25FyADyIAGQZy4jxARmnCxRAExLZKgMwa5RACxcA3IUIhUDULBygAxtAAm5QiQqgAcnVABRcVltEADxUADSgAAZ6ACQA3syw6OSQAL7hAHygKuQMDgDOEdExFuBJoABKqaAA-OWgAFyM5ABuSUA))

For the above piece of code `N` will be equivalent to `"0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4"`. How can I convert that to a numeric type, i.e. `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`?
Have already tried putting  `& number` in some places, like `infer R & number`, but none of that works.

Comment: It seems to be impossible at the moment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410801/is-it-possible-to-infer-string-to-number-in-typescript

Comment: You can create a hashmap data structure and map from `"1" -> 1` but it is not generic and it works only for 10 digits

Comment: @captain-yossarian TBH I prefer just to create `type N = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4` manualy until a TS built-in solution is available. Thanks for idea though

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**6 June 2022 UPDATE TS 4.8**

Since TypeScript 4.8, it is possible without numeric union hack. See [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094)

```js
//in my code
type ParseInt<T extends `text${number}`> =
  T extends any
  ? (T extends `text${infer Digit extends number}`
    ? Digit
    : never)
  : never

// 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
type Result = ParseInt<"text0" | "text1" | "text2" | "text3" | "text4">
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpn9xw)

**UPDATE**

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type Mapped<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : Mapped<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
    )


type NumberRange = Mapped<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number] // 0.. 998


type ConvertToNumber<T extends string, Range extends number> =
    (Range extends any
        ? (`${Range}` extends T
            ? Range
            : never)
        : never)

type _ = ConvertToNumber<'5', NumberRange> // 5
type __ = ConvertToNumber<'125', NumberRange> // 125
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20211012#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgggDQJIwKowPpwDLYPIDqAogCIYBCeqAciXAEoCaUAvFAJycCwAUL6JFgBDMJAAmAHl5QZUalAgAPYBAB2YgM5RVAVwC2AIwgAnADTTZ9CBp0AbYAuVrNUOMeNCQEnaoDWqgHsAd1UAPlYoAG0AXXMeWShwlgsZAAorG3tIgHJbNQBzYAALbOjHFXUtahSEqAB%20KAy7YBqEgC5hUQhJalMogDpBpvs%204eAcvNVCkujo0JqASl5lngFoan0jY3ohKeg2GBFxCXhkNEwcfGIySho6JlDI3UMTaJX%20cGgAYQDVADcTMAACoBDYvYwSIHlZxaDTAYwASymo12%20WgSgqLmeWySNXSqPRTkqUF2IFasgaqQABgASADeOz2AF8qdDiUDybV6o0CZzah1VBAAcYlvEuVABUKTKKPoIMBEfv9ASCwVsJNkAKzZPqqkyMtHhAD0hqgGtl0Aw8rYiuFwNBmxM6oAjAAmLU6h3bAlGk2us18HhAA)

P.S. sorry for naming, I'm not strong in it.

Seems to be it is currently impossible but there is a workaround.

You can create `Dictionary` for numbers in range `0..42`:

```js
// from a library
type Texts<T extends PropertyKey> = T extends number ? `text${T}` : never

type T = null | "auto" | Texts<Enumerate<43>>;

type PrependNextNum<A extends Array<unknown>> = A['length'] extends infer T ? ((t: T, ...a: A) => void) extends ((...x: infer X) => void) ? X : never : never;

type EnumerateInternal<A extends Array<unknown>, N extends number> = { 0: A, 1: EnumerateInternal<PrependNextNum<A>, N> }[N extends A['length'] ? 0 : 1];

type Enumerate<N extends number> = EnumerateInternal<[], N> extends (infer E)[] ? E : never;

type Dictionary = {
    [Prop in Enumerate<43> as `${Prop}`]: Prop
}

//  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 ... 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42
type N =
    Extract<T, `text${number}`> extends `text${infer R}`
    ? R extends keyof Dictionary
    ? Dictionary[R]
    : never
    : never
```

It might be possible to generate much longer range after [Tail recursion PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711) will be merged

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ByIgAmCKpCLJCIAVgiADYIgB2CIADgiAE4Ihyta9QKl2-5Up2Fz2F-2F0OF6OFxP-MkG6Bkk3d839ZRqTJE8novQsJGWAdDOwzBbIFZpErlI+TKYPdoAEpWJeSZ6H+rqgG0EjQOAoBhpG0axvgBDJsCsFRjG2A4IMf6zEB-owpAuFQvhOSEEAA)

**UPDATE** - just like I promised

Try

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type Mapped<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : Mapped<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
    )

// 0 , 1, 2 ... 998
type NumberRange = Mapped<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number]


type Texts<T extends PropertyKey> = T extends number ? `text${T}` : never


type T = null | "auto" | Texts<NumberRange>;

type Dictionary = {
    [Prop in NumberRange as `${Prop}`]: Prop
}

//  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 ... 998
type N =
    Extract<T, `text${number}`> extends `text${infer R}`
    ? R extends keyof Dictionary
    ? Dictionary[R]
    : never
    : never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210908#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgggDQJIwKowPpwDLYPIDqAogCIYBCeqAciXAEoCaUAvFACwCcArALABQA0JFgBDMJAAmAHgFR5UalAgAPYBAB2kgM5QNAVwC2AIwgAnADRyF9CNv0AbYMrWadUOGbOiQ0-RoBrDQB7AHcNAD5WKABtAF0rfgUoKJZreQAKW3snGIByB00Ac2AACzy4l3UtXWp05KgAfihsx2B65IAuMQkIGWoLWIA6EdanQbHgfMKNEvK4uIj6gEoBAQB6dagABihBgEZBgCYoEaGOTnYhcGhqI1MzelFZ6DYYcSlpeGQ0TBx8YhkSg0OhMCIxAwmcxxNaCfjCaAAFVUwG00kRVTcugACmZgpAzKAANIQECpKAYlFYvT3cxNKAAA3UagAJABvREAXwZUG6GggADdzLDriIMWwDA4HFAAD5QABEon0wGC8tlFJRaLuUMezyKEAiAG5YQioCQAJYAY2A5uCGlEZhA0TZ9RiuPxUHNGkUtN1Lygol0DPZ7rA3Li3VDAk5sM28l2cv26pOcoAzOr2OruOqAGzqgDs6oAHOrOOr9rszhcrvCbopWPUiGpvNb0YMmSj2ZCHtyolSaozmcB2V6AGZ0%20jc%20rNeiYgcBUnBUdmq02u0OkDTlfW232x0xegwpIKPmC4XH%20SnoVmEX8IA)

You can try above solution in TS playground with TS version 4.5 (nightly)
The code is much simpler.

Here you have javascript representation of `Mapped`:

```js
const Mapped = (N: number, Result: number[] = []): number[] => {
    if (Result.length === N) {
        return Result
    }
    return Mapped(N, [...Result, Result.length])
}
```

Nothing complicated. Tail recursion.

---

Comment: Ooh. A new PR from the boss-man himself. TailRec in the type-system would be an awesome addition :)

Comment: @spender true. I already have a lot of answers to improve ))

Comment: I'm gonna need a second to understand what's going on here, but it might be an overkill for what I need. Thanks for this idea though

Comment: I will add more description at the evening

Comment: This answer helped me find what I really wanted, `\`${number}\``

Comment: let me add a use case for this amazing answer, in case anyone has the same need. I needed to represent a type for numbers in a range [1960,2999], this is my approach `type a = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;
type b = 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type e = `19${b}${a}`;
type f = `2${a}${a}${a}`;

type ToYear<T extends `${number}`> =
  T extends any
  ? (T extends `${infer Years extends number}`
    ? Years
    : never)
  : never

export type BudgetYears =  ToYear<e|f> ;`  I apologize for the bad naming.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, @captain-yossarian. I found you can also keep the tuple of `Mapped<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>` and index using string index. Of course, `Range` must be a tuple.

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type Mapped<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : Mapped<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
    )


type NumberRange = Mapped<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>; // <- tuple [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]


type ConvertToNumber<T extends string, Range extends number[]> = 
  T extends keyof Range ? Range[T] : never;

type _ = ConvertToNumber<'5', NumberRange> // 5
type __ = ConvertToNumber<'125', NumberRange> // 125
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20211012#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgggDQJIwKowPpwDLYPIDqAogCIYBCeqAciXAEoCaUAvFAJycCwAUL6JFgBDMJAAmAHl5QZUalAgAPYBAB2YgM5RVAVwC2AIwgAnADTTZ9CBp0AbYAuVrNUOMeNCQEnaoDWqgHsAd1UAPlYoAG0AXXMeWShwlgsZAAorG3tIgHJbNQBzYAALbOjHFXUtahSEqAB+KAy7YBqEgC5hUQhJalMogDpBpvs+4eAcvNVCkujo0JqASl5lngFoan0jY3ohKeg2GBFxCXhkNEwcfGIySho6JlCAbhX+cGgAYQDVADcTYAAVAIbQwmCT-crOLQaYDGACWU1Gu3y0CUFRcuhBxhiSQs4NRkKgvggIACADNGkjoA0dntIv8yh1VBBfsZnnxVm8oBgIp8fn9AcCthJsgBWbJ9QUmGnI8IAellUBFr0EGG5bF5LIBQM2oOyAEYAExiiU67aUuUKw1K9lAA)

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to the @captain-yossarian-from-ukraine answer: you can skip `extends any` part and just write:

```
type ParseInt<T extends `text${number}`> =
  (T extends `text${infer Digit extends number}`
    ? Digit
    : never)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?importHelpers=true&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&keyofStringsOnly=false&ssl=4&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QJIDtgB4AqUIAewE6AJklAAbFEAkA3ugK4C2ARhAgL6UB8UAXgCwAKChQAFHkLEyFajIYBLdADNOUACJKA5kuD4iJclGbtOPUePEB%20Lbv1XrALlMQAbpwCUo0QHo-KAAGKAAfKABGMKgAJmiAZmiAFlFQSCgAJQgkJgAbAwFYRBQMbAAiGmAgsuiKmQia8LqiGMaoZuB4to6kst4gA)