# Typescript keyof array includes prototype methods

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3] as const;

type Keys = keyof typeof arr;

type T = {
  [K in Keys]: K extends 1 ? 2 : 3 // dummy
}
```

Why does the `T` type contain the `prototype keys`:

[image]

I'm expecting the keys to be only `0`, `1`, `2` in this case. How can I get only the array keys?

How can we create a new type from an array by looping over its keys?

Comment: Let me know if this answer is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216315/why-cant-i-create-a-type-of-valid-indexes-into-a-const-array/69219594#69219594

Comment: In fact there are no `number` indexes in the tuple. All indexes are stringified

Comment: See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#property_names : `Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string. This outputs 'value', since 1 is coerced into '1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Why `K extends 1` does not evaluate to true ?**

Because TS should be consistent with pure javascript property access algorithm. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#property_names).

> property names are string or Symbol. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string. This outputs 'value', since 1 is coerced into '1'.

Despite the fact that arrays/tuples are indexed by number, all their indexes are stringified under the hood of JS engine. This is why `const result = arr['1'] // 2` is perfectly valid from TS point of view.

All number keys are *de-facto* strings.

See this exmaple:

```js
declare var record: Record<number, string>

const result = record['2'] // string
const result2 = record[2] // string
const result3 = record['hello'] // expected error
```

2. **How can I get only the array keys?** - this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216315/why-cant-i-create-a-type-of-valid-indexes-into-a-const-array/69219594#69219594) answer
3. **Can you explain why you're doing:**

`T extends ${number} instead of T extends number`?

Example:

```js
type FilterNumbers<T extends PropertyKey> = T extends `${number}` ? T : never
```

`T extends` ${number}`` - literally means if `T` extends a stringified number.

Here you have another one example:

```js
type StringNumber<T extends `${number}`> = T

type Test = StringNumber<'42'> // ok

type Test1 = StringNumber<'-0.3'> // ok
type Test2 = StringNumber<`${typeof NaN}`> // ok, but in fact is a drawback
type Test3 = StringNumber<`01`> // ok, but also drawback

type Test4 = StringNumber<'hello'> // error
```

[PLayground](http://tsplay.dev/Nn4zqW)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why you're doing T extends `${number}` instead of T extends number`?

Comment: @undefined made an update

Comment: @undefined if you want to make some validators for number, I mean to disallow negative and fractions, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281203/how-to-create-a-generic-union-type-related-to-the-other-one/69281947#69281947