# How to create a generic union type related to the other one?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a union type consist of numbers related to the other prop value.

```
type Props = { numberOfPoints: number; activeItem: number }
```

If `numberOfPoints = 3` so `activeItem` be a union type consist of `1 | 2 | 3` according to `numberOfPoints` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirements:
You need to use TypeScript **nightly**

Similar question/answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type)

The code:

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type ComputeRange<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, [...Result, 0]['length']]>
    )

type Props<PointsCount extends number> = {
    numberOfPoints: PointsCount; activeItem: ComputeRange<PointsCount>
}

type Destructure<T extends Props<any>> =
    T extends { numberOfPoints: infer Count; activeItem: infer Union }
    ? Union extends number[]
    ? { numberOfPoints: Count; activeItem: Union[number] }
    : never
    : never

type Result = Destructure<Props<3>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFkCCANAkvAqvA%20ogMngPIDqAogCLYBChGAcuYgEoCasAvLACwCcArCAgxYAYQD2AW0gBXUNCYBDAHYBzaAB5gsbbDqxoADzlKAJgGdYS6RIBG0AE4AaLTqbQz0gDah9R6KYtEe3sFcHVpJQBrJTEAdyUAPg5YAG0AXWcdWCT2F20ACjcPbxSAck9-FVAAC1K032NzXTys2AB%20WCKvUBasgC5RSRk5RVUNOkdUgDoZru9JlJmpudBJgAY0sorVGrq0hJaASkEoOAAFezFIM3UzsQBLJVAzcQifQ0aLK1sHHNgAbxa3zs9kIADM7o9ngNIU8XmI3gBuWAKADGoHuADdoKg5BIBuIpLJ5Mo1LcHnDXk8DgBfE7CcjuUD2aTo6T2DQAFQa-iaFyuN2U4ASORa3I%20vIs-0s1hB4Nh0NgjzBDkGSJR6KxOLxA2VqowSnuYiUsDpWQ6BqNJolARlP3s6RaHWlwIc8opiqpoGRaIx2Nx0HxsEtxpSrvs9TNOgGSmg2PsLRjcYc9LgK2SjLMzNZoHZGn513UAGYRSAgA)

**Explanation**

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711) PR increases a limit of recursive types.

`ComputeRange` - creates empty array on first call and checks whether the length of an array equals `N` generic argument. If not, calls recursively itself with same first argument and extended version of second argument (with extra element). This approach allows us to keep track of array length.

Each element of array is the length of `Result` during each iteration.

`Destructure` helps you to get the union of all elements in array. You are unable to do `ComputeRange<PointsCount>[number]` in `Props` directly because of the recursion.

**Caveats** (thanks @jcalz for pointing it)

---

You still are allowed to use negative numbers, typeof Infinity and fractionals.

```js
// activeItem: any;
type _ = Props<2.3>

// activeItem: []
type __ = Props<number>

// activeItem: any;
type ___ = Props<0.000001>

// activeItem: [];
type ____ = Props<typeof Infinity>
```

The better way is to restrict `Props` argument:

```js
type AllowedRange = ComputeRange<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number]

type Props<PointsCount extends AllowedRange> = {
    numberOfPoints: PointsCount; activeItem: ComputeRange<PointsCount>
}
```

See full code:

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type ComputeRange<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, [...Result, 0]['length']]>
    )

type AllowedRange = ComputeRange<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number]

type Props<PointsCount extends AllowedRange> = {
    numberOfPoints: PointsCount; activeItem: ComputeRange<PointsCount>
}

type Destructure<T extends Props<any>> =
    T extends { numberOfPoints: infer Count; activeItem: infer Union }
    ? Union extends number[]
    ? { numberOfPoints: Count; activeItem: Union[number] }
    : never
    : never
/**
 * Ok
 */

type Ok0 = Destructure<Props<42>> // ok
type Ok1 = Destructure<Props<600>> // ok

/**
 * Fails
 */
// activeItem: any;
type _ = Props<2.3>

// activeItem: []
type __ = Props<number>

// activeItem: any;
type ___ = Props<0.000001>

// activeItem: [];
type ____ = Props<typeof Infinity>
```

Please keep in mind, these things with recursion could boil a glass of water on your CPU :D

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/Wy5KJW)

---

If you don't want to pay a huge amount of money for electricity, you can add some validators for `number` argument:

```js
type ComputeRange<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, [...Result, 0]['length']]>
    )

type IsFraction<T extends number> = `${T}` extends `${number}.${number}` ? true : false
type IsNegative<T extends number> = `${T}` extends `-${number}` ? true : false
type IsNotLiteral<T> = T extends number ? number extends T ? true : false : false

type Either<Validators extends boolean[]> = Validators[number] extends false ? true : false

type IsValid<PointsCount extends number> = Either<[
    IsFraction<PointsCount>,
    IsNegative<PointsCount>,
    IsNotLiteral<PointsCount>
]
>
{
    type Test = IsValid<2.3> // false
    type Test1 = IsValid<-1> // false
    type Test2 = IsValid<number> // false

}

type Props<
    PointsCount extends number> =
    IsValid<PointsCount> extends false ? never : {
        numberOfPoints: PointsCount; activeItem: ComputeRange<PointsCount>
    }

type Destructure<T> =
    T extends { numberOfPoints: infer Count; activeItem: infer Union }
    ? Union extends number[]
    ? { numberOfPoints: Count; activeItem: Union[number] }
    : never
    : never
/**
 * Returns union
 */

type Ok0 = Destructure<Props<2>> // expected result

/**
 * Never
 */
type _ = Props<2.3>
type __ = Props<number> 
type ___ = Props<0.000001>
type ____ = Props<typeof Infinity>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAV2BASgQwHYHMIA8AUFKVAHJQQAea2AJgM5TbIIBGEATgDQlnoIjZABtgVWhAbMAgly6YQBZNgDW2OAHdsAPigBeKAG0AunzJQ9%20-qQAUg4WKMByEVNzAAFs5MS6TChsLKAB%20KAdRYCCLAC5YRBQ0LDxCch5jADosiLF0oyyMnOB0gAYTFzc8Lx8THSCASiIiUEgoAElGADEFAGNgAEs4bAIAFT8pANYObisoAAMAEgBvEYBfOfHpeeWpzi5VjJ22PfXQqGAuZGg4gDNMEUYIZvBoDvIIXEwBgDdCMZp-MxdjMDNsVqcARNmHMALRHab7DZhC5XKC3e6PZ6tN5wYAAGX6aAUIlGs3%20ki2wK4ZypmwCY2Rl2uUDuD2ZrMxWOgAFFCZ5uAQAGr3fr0L5wLjMSFbdhwOBuHCmWbCkSi8WSoxU3zSgIc6CM1HotlNFqvRgq0UEAAKcH62GAjHgKnEOqBxxBhl5XgFRiCHW6mD6g2GNrtDqd9p05jIbw%20X36v2ttvtjrgzqjfsY5FxBKJ9yTYdT6aIJiIdSWQVNUBGQnEhg6FvoBAATBkAMx6AD0nZZGKeFirNcYwAAjKCGyKmzCR12e3rKy9q7Xm%20PzZOCFTZ73jURVibF1auHAwIxiBZQymIy6KZN3VwrJnGwXL2nI3TmHqaRBftS4hXgmQVIAPI3BeDpxGBRb2gA3FAgY-BAbRoAgcTwEgqAYDg%20DPuGr7AHUFh7lyUAACK1pcfTIFwfwPhY5KAlASwsHeIGQXEdo3Nw8TOrB8EJohyHsdgnHUgAqtgwZQHuFhhOJkmusxCKmEEYRMcBoHJuB3EwXBQa-EhEAoVAclDJqd6%20NJZBxNg37cEE1m2VwRCdgAVC5JAueEEDAFR2DMCowYeZ2%206tEBqglKCZHDhRPnUdaR4ni2OhbjQkB9BA9BQNRjhRM5bkeRQjlBcRAD6oKHsep6th2pVlYYFWJZuUC1XVUANaeJQZCU3XdTOLWte1BCmnANztMJdqEiAOhAA)

`IsFraction`, `IsNegative`, `IsNotLiteral` will check whether your argument is valid or not. Please consider adding more tests.

P.S. More explanation you can find in my [article](https://catchts.com/range-numbers)

Comment: Your playground link is broken; could you fix it?  I think things like this are fun but you should probably present caveats here, since recursive types that compare numbers to array lengths tend to do... *interesting* things when those numbers are negative or have fractional parts (e.g., `-2` or `2.5`).

Comment: @jcalz added more information. I hope to see an upvote from you :D

Comment: I'm so sorry for the delay @captain-yossarian. Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer ️

Comment: @MohammadRezaGhasemi no problem at all . Thank you for your feedback!