# Typescript: how to define a object with many unknown keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm building an application that access an API that returns an object with many unknown keys, each key represents an id of a user.

Example:

```
const response = {
  "random id1": {name: "user1"},
  "random id2": {name: "user2"},
  ...
  "random id100": {name: "user100"}
}
```

I know that if I have just one unknown key I can define using something like:

```
type MyDefinition = {
  [key: string]: Metadata
}
```

But how can I define an object with so many different keys?

Comment: `[key: string]` allows for multiple unknown keys though, as long as they're all strings

Comment: What limits the latter to "one key"? You could also use `type MyDefinition = { [key: \`random id${number}\`]: MetaData; }`, but that's just if you want it more precise (and it would still not match perfectly, as it allows generic numbers, e.g. "random id1e4").

Comment: The answers you're getting here seem like they specifically are dealing with keys literally of the form `"random id123"` but I assume that the actual random ids you're talking about don't have any such constraint on them.  In which case you should just use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) as @Samathingamajig has suggested (and should probably post as an answer).  Index signatures do not restrict to a single key and I'm not sure what gave you that idea; is that something you ran into somewhere?

Comment: @Samathingamajig you solved my problem. I didn't know this allows multiple keys. If you post an answer I would be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[key: string]` allows for any amount of unique strings as keys.

```
type Metadata = {
  name: string
}

type MyDefinition = {
  [key: string]: Metadata
}

const response: MyDefinition = {
  "random id1": {name: "user1"},
  "random id2": {name: "user2"},
  // ...
  "random id100": {name: "user100"},
};
```

Try it on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwEMAmDFQLxQN4CgpQDsEBbCALigGdgAnASwIHMcBfHHUSWEAEQgDMGdYHQD2BDNjxQA2gGsIICtXpMAuhTiIUiVuwDG46lBoRKYI+W59BBYWImZc+AEQ0EBJKOJQ6SAIwuFFhEpBQuAK6UEDSBLAA00m4eXj5+AExB2KFWkdE0mQnSAPTFUAB0lUnunt6+AQAMDVkhJLlRMf5NLkUsANw4QA)

Answer (score 4):

Extending @ASDFGerte comment. You can generate a range of numbers from 0 to 998 in typescript 4.5:

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type ComputeRange<
  N extends number,
  Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
  > =
  (Result['length'] extends N
    ? Result
    : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
  )

// 0 , 1, 2 ... 998
type NumberRange = ComputeRange<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number]

type Name<T extends string> = { name: T }

type CustomResponse = {
  [Prop in NumberRange]: Record<`random id${Prop}`, Name<`id${Prop}`>>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQQBoEk4FU4H0EBlcDyA6gKIAiWAQgegHJkIBKAmjALwwCc3woksAYQD2AWwgBXEFEYBDAHYBzKAB5gMGLRhQAHlLkATAM4w54kQCMoAJwA0amIyiHxAGxBbdUA8YRWrMsGVxOQBrOSEAdzkAPnYYAG0AXTt1WLZ7AApHZzd4gHIXLwUQAAs8xI89Iw17dQB%20BydXEFqYAC4YYTFJaXklZVobBIA6UezmofHcgqLS8sTo%20wBKXgB6VZgABhghgEYhgCYYUeGuTgAOPmgNM0srWUVYDi6JKQf%20xFQMbDxCUgpqHQGCxovFTBZrIleOBrrQZCIVAAVSpeaqGEBWACWijSMAA3iZ4VAOsiAL68K6CcTo0TZCBCOSGJ74%20zxAAKViEEBg2JuEPufSgiQ6jgAxkIrPplAADfwGUQ8-QAEjxHK5pOlQzhCJlmOVqs5EA10UW5OAQA)

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type) and [here](https://catchts.com/range-numbers) you can find an explanation of number range.

You have probable noticed that there is a limit you can't cross.

With above approach it will not allow `random id1e4`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type defined with a template string like this:

```
const response: { [key: `random id${number}`]: { name: string }} = {
  "random id1": {name: "user1"},
  "random id2": {name: "user2"},
  "random id100": {name: "user100"}
}
```

You can see it in action on this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgB3BBAuGBvGBtAawQE8sADOAQzABMQBbGASxoBJswBXegIwTgC%20ZALpYOlephjQ4TMAHMBAmAF4cAKBgwARFVoNmNAIzaxYCVO2d0cEwIA0mnXrqMWAJlM5zkrFZueDk661K6GRgAMEV7ivjrW-JHRAuoCQA).