# How do I define a typescript type with a repeating structure？

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type that looks something like this:

```
type Location=`${number},${number};${number},${number};...`
```

Is there a Utility type like `Repeat<T>` that can do this for me?
like this:

```
type Location=Repeat<`${number},${number};`>
```

Comment: why not just give type as `string`

Comment: because I want to narrow my  type

Comment: then just declare it with `const location = any_value` then type will be the `any_value`...

Answer (score 6):

**IT WORKS ONLY IN TS >=4.5**

It is possible to create standalone type.

Please see this example:

```js
type Coordinates = `${number},${number};`

type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 50

type Last<T extends string[]> = T extends [...infer _, infer Last] ? Last : never;

type ConcatPrevious<T extends any[]> = Last<T> extends string ? `${Last<T>}${Coordinates}` : never

type Mapped<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [Coordinates],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : Mapped<N, [...Result, ConcatPrevious<Result>]>
    )


// type MyLocation = 
// | `${number},${number};` 
// | `${number},${number};${number},${number};` 
// | `${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};` 
// | `${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};` 
// | `${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};` 
// | ... 44 more ... 
// | `${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number};${number},${number}; ....

type MyLocation = Mapped<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number]

const myLocation1: MyLocation = '45,56;67,68;' // ok
const myLocation2: MyLocation = '45,56;67,68;1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8;9,10;' // ok
const myLocation3: MyLocation = '45,56;67,68;1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8;9,10,' // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBe2Dw)

`Mapped` types is an utility type which represents a `while` loop. It iterates until length of `Result` will reach `N`. In other words `Mapped<10>` - will iterate 10 times.
See this example in pure js:

```js
const mapped = (N: number, Result: any[] = []): string => {
    if (N === Result.length) {
        return Result.join('')
    }
    
    const x = Math.random();
    const y = Math.random()
    return mapped(N, [...Result, `${x},${y};`])
}
```

It is hard to represent unions in js, thats why I have used `join('')`. I hope it is clear how it works.

If you want to increase `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY` to 500 it will heat your CPU so be careful.

As you might have noticed, it is impossible in type script to represent recursive pattern for type but it is possible to create big enough union.

Please keep in mind that there are some drawbacks of `${number}` type. You are allowed to use numbers with leading zero like here:

```js
const x: `${number}` = '01'.
```

### **Useful links**:

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type) you can find an example how you can create a range of numbers  using this pattern.
2. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711) you can find a PR where this feature was introduced
3. [Here](https://catchts.com/range-numbers) and [here](https://catchts.com/even-length#recursive_pattern) you can find my articles which are related to this pattern

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to define an infinite repeating pattern for a type that you use on variable declaration.

However, a type guard on a function can check that a string matches an infinite pattern, like so ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsAxgCwgZwAoOBATgOwB4tgcCoIAPHfAEzSjWFwEt8BzAGigGEBXXLgj5gFasPqNmbdgD4oAXl4ChIsTUkADTVAD8U1hygAuKAAp+g4aKoaGmgCQBvEmXwBfZ2wBmeKACV0YHcdfXgkVExsPCJXGO5ApnlTfAgANzwASgBuAChc0EgoABkAe0QEFlL8OPIlRyd8PgBbACM8d05nJraO7M083NoIRAAbOCEobz58RGAq-Chq0ZAAQURECDBgNDKK+erCYvUJBiZDdigAMigASV3yyurue72nxaVwlHRaojeDmrRAjcYqyWRmUaPAGmYqZUxpUosWiDZZrDZbHb-BZmABEAEYAEycADMABZsgBWABsnAA7AAObI4nJQAD0rKggF4NwCyO1Bmghvgx8qj1pttg99tj8USyZSaQzmdk2RzAAVkgHg-qC0UroKD4UqifkRYX4FaijES964wkAcll1LpjMVyqg6s12oYeoNAuQxtN6PFWOqVs4MuypIpnCptKZLPZLo1Wp1nr53qAA)):

```js
type MatchesPattern<Pattern extends string, Current extends string> = Current extends `` ? string : (Current extends `${Pattern}${infer Rest}` ? MatchesPattern<Pattern, Rest> : never);

type LocationPattern = `${number},${number};`;

declare function onlyAcceptsLocation<L extends string & IsLocation, IsLocation = MatchesPattern<LocationPattern, L>>(location: L): void;

onlyAcceptsLocation("12,34;56,78;"); //  matches 

onlyAcceptsLocation("12,34;56,78"); // ⚠️

onlyAcceptsLocation("12'34;56,78;"); // ⚠️

onlyAcceptsLocation("1,2,3;45,67;"); // ⚠️
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly choose type `string` if you want as:

```
type myLocation = string;
const myLocation: myLocation = "123123123";

console.log(myLocation);
```

else if you want to narrow it down then better to declare it `const` as:

```
const myLocation = "123123123";
console.log(myLocation);
```

then your type will be the value of the `myLocation`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed this from my other TS challenge where I try to mix console colors [*(gist)*](https://gist.github.com/ackvf/68f992660a5eda645c4671d3599b2acf#file-colorizer-proxy-ts), it detects unlimited repetitions, but I haven't figured out how to practically apply it as a guard. So this is more like a fun exercise.

```
type ValidCodes = `${number}` //"0" | "1" | "2" | "31" | "32" | "33"

type Tail<T> = T extends [infer _FirstItem, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : never

type Merge<A extends ValidCodes[]> = Tail<A>['length'] extends 0
  ? A[0]
  // @ts-expect-error Type 'DotMergeTuple<Tail<A>>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.
  : `${A[0]};${Merge<Tail<A>>}`


type Split<T> = T extends `${infer A};${infer B}`
  ? [A, ...Split<B>]
  : [T]


type T01 = Merge<['1', '1', '33', '31']>
type T02 = Split<'0;1;2;31;32'>

type T = Merge<Split<'0;1;2;31;33;x'>> // Type "x" is not assignable to type `${number}`.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `as const` assertion to get a string literal type from a template literal, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBGGBeGByBj0G4BQoksCATKjAAYAkA3lgL4A0tDOLUST7nFMAhhBiFoOGAHoxMKAE8ADgFMYAS0EAiLIyw4NWVUA)

```ts
const str1 = 'str1';
const str2 = `${str1},${str1};${str1},${str1}` as const; // type is "str1,str1;str1,str1"
```