# TypeScript string alias repeated substring

Tags: typescript, string, substring, repeat, type-alias

I want to create an alias for WKT strings. So I declared a type like below:

```ts
type WicketCoordinates = `${number} ${number}` | `${number} ${number} ${number}`;
```

Now it is simple to build alias for `POINT`. But when it comes to other geometries like `LineString` I need an string which is a comma separated of n-times repeats of type `WicketCoordinates`.

By that I mean I want a type that can accept all of these below:

```ts
let a = "12 34"; // One single WicketCoordinates
let b = "12 34,56 78"; // A combination of two WicketCoordinates separated by comma
let c = "12 34,56 78,90 12"; // A combination of three WicketCoordinates separated by comma
let d = "12 34,56 78, ... ,90 12"; // A combination of n-times WicketCoordinates separated by comma
```

So I tried declaring this type:

```ts
type WicketCommaSeperatedCoordinates = WicketCoordinates | `${WicketCoordinates},${WicketCoordinates}` | `${WicketCommaSeperatedCoordinates},${WicketCommaSeperatedCoordinates}`;
```

but that comes with `circularly references itself` error. So I tried this type:

```ts
type WicketCommaSeperatedCoordinates = {
  value:
    | WicketCoordinates
    | `${WicketCoordinates},${WicketCoordinates}`
    | `${WicketCommaSeperatedCoordinates['value']},${WicketCommaSeperatedCoordinates['value']}`;
};
```

But that also comes with `referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation` error.

**The absolute question**: Is there any way in typescript to declare a type which is an alias string made of n-times repeats of a substring?

Comment: Don't think that's possible, as your union type will be literal and by self-referencing itself will lead to recursion (which is what the error is about). It will have a type definition of infinite length.

Comment: @Terry How infinity becomes a problem since the ```type X = `${number}`;``` is also infinite but accepted?

Comment: That's not infinite. That's simply a literal type. However your case you need to account for arbitrary number of comma separated numbers that cannot be represented by a primitive literal type.

Comment: @FarhadRad are you looking for something like [this](https://catchts.com/even-length#recursive_pattern) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718896/how-do-i-define-a-typescript-type-with-a-repeating-structure#answer-70720063) ?

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/Wo52PN) you have a plyagorund

Comment: @Terry in terms of infinity, you are right, but you can create big enough union type. For instance, you can create a type with 100 unions, where each element is bigger by one.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot account for all use-cases: i.e. any arbitrary number of comma separated numbers

Comment: @Terry I only can create maximum of allowed size union, which might be enough in some cases. But it still have a size.

Comment: There is no *specific* type in TypeScript that works this way; you can write a *generic* type constraint and helper function which works for arbitrary lengths like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXjBDm), at the expense of making everything that handles this type generic.  Does that address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz if you want me to be notified of a reply)