# TypeScript type for stringified values of a number union type

Tags: typescript, dry, union-types

I am trying to define a TypeScript type that restricts values to the string versions of a set of numbers. Explanation below:

Say I have a union numeric type like so:

```
const ONE = 1;
const TWO = 2;

type ALLOWED_NUMBER = typeof ONE | typeof TWO;
```

I would like to also define a companion string type that only allows the stringified versions of these numbers. So that I could do the following:

```
type ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = /* insert solution here :) */

const numericStringA: ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = '1';    // no error
const numericStringB: ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = '3';    // error
const numericStringC: ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = 'foo';  // error
```

I could manually define this type but it would be great to avoid the redundancy!

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4PlN) you can find dry generic solution and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type#answer-69090186) you can find an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBA8gOQKIwLwwIwG4BQpKwAqA6nGjAEy45QCeADgKYwCCAMm3MUgCID6CAKoBZAEJIASuTpMQAM3jIYAHxgzG8mCTi51rDl14CR4iXwDKhCQEkEAcXIADACQBvdp278hYyQF9HanxoGDAAVwBbRgAnAEtgcyg4sABzFgAufU8jH1MLK1sHdAByDGKg8BDwqLiEpNjU0UyPQ28TSXybe3JigGZymAB6ACocGHGJgD1pmdnZnEIGZmKAIl6V4phYiFCQWABDCAhYlLB9gCMAG2YoEDUlmFWMFZUYFYoNgDoACgpeigoAEoYMNBjg8JVYNUYvFEskUgBhZoGLzGXxmSxdIqPOQgEADEZjCbjOakmYLB6rXEgDZbHZgPYwQ7HU4Xa5qO56J4vVTvL6-f5AkFgoA)

```ts
const ONE = 1;
const TWO = 2;

type ALLOWED_NUMBER = typeof ONE | typeof TWO;
type ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = `${ALLOWED_NUMBER}`;

const numericStringA: ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = '1';

const numericStringB: ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = '3'; /*
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type '"3"' is not assignable to type '"1" | "2"'.(2322) */

const numericStringC: ALLOWED_NUMBER_STRING = 'foo'; /*
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"1" | "2"'.(2322) */
```

---

And, for a collection of numbers, you can make it DRYer this way:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=63&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwSA7gUwCYDkCuBbAIzQCcIYBeGAbQEYAaGAJgYGYBdeM0SKAbgCgoATwAOaGAEEkqTLkIkKMYWJAAzeNPTZ8RUlTA6SbXjAD0pmDRgAfJjZgtBo8VORa5ugMpRiigAYAJADerjLa8sQAvn4m5jAARDTx9vGMybbxLPH8-NzQMAZ4JACWwN7ExWAA5hIAXJKasobE5YoA5DRtArng+YUlZT6VVQBC9aHuza2UbQAsXWYAVPwwq2sAeptb29v8ACrOMG3xs-FtMMVkYCCwcBAQxVVgcAQI4lAgSofHSSlpKVk2gA6AAUjBYjEYAEoYItTDk8rB+hVBhVqgBhcaNcJeHztVQgEALUzLNYbHYUzb7b7xAkgM4XK43TgPJ4vN5KT7KcQ-dIJf4ZQGg8GQmFw-hAA)

```ts
const allowedNumbers = [1, 2, 3] as const;
type AllowedNumber = typeof allowedNumbers[number]; // 1 | 2 | 3
type AllowedNumberStr = `${AllowedNumber}`; // "1" | "2" | "3"
```