# How do I write an IndexOf<Array, T> type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a readonly array of strings and numbers.  I want to have a reverse map object similar to how [reverse mapping of `enum`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) work.  In order to do this, I need to be able to find the index of `T` within array `A`.

```ts
const myArray = [1, '1+', 2, 3, '3+'] as const;

type MyArrayIndexes = {
  [K in typeof myArray[number]]: IndexOf<typeof myArray, K>;
};

const myArrayIndexes: MyArrayIndexes = {
  1: 0,
  '1+': 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  '3+': 4,
};
```

I was having trouble figuring out the definition of `IndexOf<A extends readonly any[], T extends A[number]>`, but thought I'd play with it a bit longer before I asked SO.  I figured it out, so I thought I'd share in case anyone else looked to do this.

My initial implementation was something like this, though originally it was using `typeof myArray` directly rather than the template parameter `A` and included some boneheaded, uninteresting mistakes.

```ts
type IndexOf<A extends readonly unknown[], T extends A[number]> = Extract<
  {
    [K in keyof A & number]: [A[K], K];
  }[keyof A & number], 
  [T, number]
>[1];
```

When I tried to instantiate `myArrayIndexes`, it was expecting every value to be `never`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Final implementation

```ts
type ParseNum<S extends string> = S extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never;

type IndexOf<A extends readonly unknown[], T extends A[number]> = Extract<
  {
    [K in keyof A & `${number}`]: [
      A[K],
      ParseNum<K>
    ];
  }[keyof A & `${number}`],
  [T, number]
>[1];
```

#### Explanation

There were two things I needed to fix.

1. `keyof` on a readonly array returns a string, not a number, so my `[K in keyof A & number]` was returning `never`.
2. I then needed a method of extracting the number, which someone else had asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69090186/3120446).  This is `ParseNum<S>` in my solution above.

I had also thought that the tuples needed to be `readonly`, but that turned out to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a recursive type:

```
type Simplify<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}
type ReverseMapping<T extends readonly PropertyKey[]> = Simplify<_ReverseMapping<T, [], {}>>

type _ReverseMapping<Tail extends readonly unknown[], Count extends 0[], Acc>
    = Tail extends readonly [infer A, ...infer B]
    ? _ReverseMapping<B, [0, ...Count], Acc & Record<A & PropertyKey, Count['length']>>
    : Acc
```

Confirming that it works: (you can get rid of the `Simplify` part if you don't need the resulting type to be readable.)

```
type Test = ReverseMapping<typeof myArray>
// type Test = {
//     1: 0;
//     "1+": 1;
//     2: 2;
//     3: 3;
//     "3+": 4;
// }
```

Usage:

```
const myArray = [1, '1+', 2, 3, '3+'] as const;
const myArrayIndexes: ReverseMapping<typeof myArray> = {
  1: 0,
  '1+': 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  '3+': 4,
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgWzAGzgMxAHgCoD4oC8UA3gNoDSUcAdlANYQgD2aU2AugFxsXsC+AKFCQoAJQgA3CACcAzhACyAQzBgaAcxxQIAD2ARqAE1lRpEJYabVkIKAAVpTSNNDlGpdviLwkqDJgB9cSk5RRU1ak1sABooD1jiPlxcASFwaCDJGXllVQ0cJThkbT0DY1NzS2tbAFdqOmomAHdqeKgAYSY64BL9IxMABjaAQQBjUZSoKcI2QuLdPvKzCysbOJo0GShh2IA6fY2tgCF2AWmoAH4oTJCc8Pyj2NIBvf3O7vZYsdGoADIxCCjJjSQyYYZ-eyOZyuRixd7UYCkADkyAM6mAAAskZ5JtNuN9UsJoNgILIekRgtkwnlIpgiSwoAgQMNpNIlCAUgB6TlQIlsUnkkgCbnnKAARm4AwA3MKeecAERigDU8u4YplIvOACZuFqNXLpgBmbiG-Wi+WGlXcAAsZsEAiB1DJjOZrPZM1IYtiSOVSNiWtihu9luxUCUJkdZJlkZ6TJZbJAAEkjLpSdxKaFchFNPTWHG3RyZsQzuLJdESz6lUi1eWpjqoAGS8aoEGKyGbeW+DKgA)