# Get numeric keys of tuples while mapping

Tags: typescript, tuples

I'm trying to map a tuple to a new one, which includes all tuple elements at each indicines before its position (`SliceStartQuantity` is an external dependecy):

```
type mappedTuple = mapTuple<[10, 20, 30, 40]> // Expect: [[], [10], [10, 20], [10, 20, 30]]

type mapTuple<T extends any[]> = {[key in keyof T]:SliceStartQuantity<T,0,key>}
```

However `mapTuple` gives an understandable error message, because `SliceStartQuantity` requires `number` at its third argument:

> Type '(number | `${number}`) & key' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'.
> Type '`${number}` & key' is not assignable to type 'number'.

My current really nasty workaround is using a prewritten "casting" type:

```
type castStringToNumber<T> = T extends '0' ? 0 : T extends '1' ? 1 : T extends '2' ? 2 : T extends '3' ? 3 : T extends '4' ? 4 : never ...etc
```

By wrapping `key (type parameter)` with this, everything works as expected:

```
type mapTuple<T extends any[]> = {[key in keyof T]:SliceStartQuantity<T,0,castStringToNumber<key>>}

// mappedTuple: [[], [10], [10, 20], [10, 20, 30]]
```

Is there any way to extract numeric keys while mapping over tuples, cleanly?

using Typescipt 4.8.4

Comment: what is `SliceStartQuantity` ?

Comment: a utility function from this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-tuple basically it behaves similarly to .slice() but in a type way

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type#answer-69090186) answer.  You can cast it like [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5zjBm)

Comment: I stripped some bit from your answer for this specific tuple purpose, and this one works perfectly:  ```type ParseInt<T> = T extends `${infer Digit extends number}` ? Digit : never``` Thank you so much, ```infer``` rules!