# Generic function Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'U'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am getting this error, Where as U is number and returning the number too.

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'U'.
```

```
function foo<T extends string, U extends number>(a: T): U {
    return +a; // error in this line
}


foo<string, number>('12')
```

Comment: you are mis-using generics here. Why not just do: `function foo(a: string): number { return +a; }` ?

Comment: Deinitely just return a `number` instead of `U`. If the actual function does need to use the generic, you could also cast the return value `return +a as U`.

Comment: to get to the "why the error is happening part": right now, you could call the function with any number literal `foo<string, 1000>('12')`. The return type would be `1000` but it actually returns `12`. That's what the compiler is trying to warn you about.

Comment: it is just an example. I know I can do that without generics.  Yes with a cast is working fine. @TobiasS. your example does not make any sense 1000 and return 12 in that case it is perfect but there we are saying it will return number and if is returning that it should not throw an error

Comment: Try [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPpnqW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it worth using overloading here:

```js
type UnsafeNumber = number & { tag?: 'UnsafeNumber' }

type ParseInt<Str extends string> =
  Str extends `${infer Digit extends number}`
  ? Digit
  : UnsafeNumber


function foo<T extends string>(a: T): ParseInt<T>
function foo<T extends string>(a: T) {
  return +a;
}

type Result = ParseInt<'.2'>

const _ = foo('42') // 42
const __ = foo('4.2') // 4.2
const ___ = foo('s03') // UnsafeNumber
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPpnqW)

Since TS does not distinguish `number` and `NaN` I have provided `UnsafeNumber` which corresponds to `NaN`. However, it is still not safe and I would recommend you to use `parseItn` function

**ParseInt** utility type

Since TS 4.8, TS is able to infer literal number from stringified number. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-inference-for-infer-types-in-template-string-types). It means that TS is able to infer `100` from `"100"`. It means that when you provide `"42"` as an argument, TS will be able to infer it as a digit `100`. If you will provide just a regular string, TS will not be able to do it and `false` branch in conditional type will be evaluated, or in other words `UnsafeType` will be returned.

`UnsafeType` is just a regular `number` with using of `branded type` pattern. So TS will be able to distinguish regular `number` and `UnsafeNumber`. `UnsafeNumber` means that TS is not able to infer digit number from string and it might be `NaN`

If you are interested and type inference and validation you can check my [this](https://catchts.com/range-numbers) article about number inference and [inference on function arguments](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) in general or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type#answer-69090186) answer

Comment: can you explain me this part  type ParseInt<Str extends string> =
  Str extends `${infer Digit extends number}`
  ? Digit
  : UnsafeNumber

Comment: @Indraraj26 provided an explanation with links

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `as` keyword to cast the return value type

```
function foo<T extends string, U extends number>(a: T): U {
    return +a as U;

}

foo<string, number>('12')
```

Comment: didn't noticed that Mike S have already answered in comment section

Comment: A comment is not an answer, don't worry :) I would, however, mention that this allows you to do something like `const a  = foo<string, 1000>('12')` which is wrong (and that's what the error is tryinfg to tell you).