# Can I programmatically convert string number literal type to its number counterpart? (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

I want to convert this union:

```
"1"|"2"|"3"
```

To it's exact number counterpart:

```
1|2|3
```

Is this possible, and how? Many thanks!

Comment: This one might technically be a better match, but it wouldn't be eligible because it doesn't have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65410801/1426891

Comment: @Michiel de Vos, try second example, like here tsplay.dev/WK8YKw

Comment: Thanks for you quick replies! That will definately do the work!